# Stripped truss rod nut on Ibanez Jem 7VP

Tags: guitar, ibanez, truss-rod

I have an Ibanez Jem 7VP, Indonesian made 2019 Premium model.
Is truss rod nut replacable on this model?

Comment: Any nut is replaceable… so long as the thread on the truss-rod isn't stripped. We would need more details on just precisely how someone managed to wreck this particular one & what the end result actually was.

Comment: I mean double action truss rod nuts are not replacable and I don't know what kind of truss rod is used on this model (single or double action). The inner hexagonal shape of the nut is stripped, the inner shape is damaged. 4mm allen key turns within the nut. The nut doesn't turn

Comment: You don't use Allen keys to turn nuts. Maybe the hex hole is in the end of the threaded trussrod. Try a slightly bigger (4.5mm) Allen key, but it sounds like the end of the 'bolt' is damaged.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u5rAfNdh9gNrhZYQcjf11JeVm8XJYdM1/view?usp=drivesdk This is the damaged part. The key just turns within it. Probably 4.5mm would work but I prefer to replace it if possible.

Comment: @Tim Could you please take a look? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u5rAfNdh9gNrhZYQcjf11JeVm8XJYdM1/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Yes, it looks like that's the head of the long bolt that is the trussrod. I'd be taking off strings, trying to hammer a 4.5mm Allen key into it, just to remove the rod. Another option may be an *imperial* Allen key, or even an 'Eazyout' bolt remover - a left hand threaded very course hardened 'screw' that bites in and turns anti-clockwise. If the hole is too big, drill another deeper one into the head of the trussrod. Good luck!

Comment: @Tim Thank you so much for the answer! So you are sure that the truss rod is a single action / removable one, right? I was looking into tech specs on Ibanez website and was unable to find any info regarding the type of truss rod.

Comment: Were it mine, that's exactly what would be happening to it.